# Rails: fb_connect_async_js provokes 500 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, facebooker2

I am a new comer in Ruby on Rails. I am currently trying to install Facebooker2 gem on my project to allow users to connect through this famous network. I followed [official installation guide](https://github.com/mmangino/facebooker2). However, I still got an issue.

When I am using *fb_connect_async_js* helper, I got a 500 error. Server logs tell me the following:

> Error during failsafe response: incompatible encoding regexp match (UTF-8 regexp with ASCII-8BIT string)

Have you any solution?

My Gemfile, if it may be useful:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'

gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'meta_search', '>= 1.1.0.pre'

gem 'devise'

gem 'mogli'
gem 'ruby-hmac'
gem 'facebooker2'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

    group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. I switch off and on again my computer, and all seem to work now. Perhaps a session variable wrongly set? Weird.