# Rails: assets:precompile encoding error when require jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, encoding, asset-pipeline

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a day; growing desperate!

`rake assets:precompile` fails with following encoding error when `//= require jquery` is included in manifest but works when it's commented out as so: `// require jquery`:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
. . .
Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '["ok","!function(e,t': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string)
  (in /rails/myapp/releases/20130920030318/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:242:in `rescue in parse_string'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:213:in `parse_string'
/rails/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/pure/parser.rb:257:in `parse_value'
. . .
```

Failing **application.js**:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require hogan.js
//= require bootstrap
//= require twitter/typeahead
// require twitter/typeahead.min
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

but change that first line and it works:

```
// require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
. . .
```

Gemfile

```
. . . 
gem 'jquery-rails'
. . .
```

Any ideas? How to troubleshoot or debug this?!?

Comment: Try something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812479/rails-fb-connect-async-js-provokes-500-error

Comment: Ruby 2, Rails 4 and the same asset list; I don't have a problem.  Did you do a `bundle exec RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean` and then recompile?

Comment: `bundle exec rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production` didn't help :-(

Comment: @user1737909 - so, you mean try something like turning on and off my computer?!?

Comment: @trh - 'same asset list'. would you mind sharing your `datatables.js` or `datatables.js.coffee`? Maybe via a [gist](https://gist.github.com). I think my problem may be in there; it's the only reference to `e` in my application.